# Lemma 21.4 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Continuity of the four basic algebraic operations

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Here is Lemma 21.2 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> The addition, subtraction, and multiplication operations are continuous functions from $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$; and the quotient operation is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R} \times \big( \mathbb{R} - \{ \ 0 \ \} \big)$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

My Attempt:

> Let the functions  $f, g, h \colon  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the formulas 
>   $$ f(x \times y) \colon= x+y, \qquad g( x\times y) \colon= x-y, \qquad h( x \times y ) \colon= xy. $$
>   And, let the function $k \colon \mathbb{R} \times \big( \mathbb{R} - \{ \ 0 \ \} \big) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by the formula
>   $$ k(x \times y) = \frac{x}{y}. $$
>
> We show that each of the functions $f, g, h, k$ is continuous by showing that the inverse image of every open set in the range space $\mathbb{R}$ under each one of these functions is an open set in its respective domain space.

Fucntion $f$:

> Let $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. If $f^{-1}(V)$ is empty, then it is trivially open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. So let us assume that $f^{-1}(V)$ is non-empty. Let $a \times b \in f^{-1}(V)$. Then $a \times b \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $f(a \times b) = a+b \in V$. So there is a real number $\varepsilon > 0$ such that 
>   $$ ( \ a+b- \varepsilon, \ a+b + \varepsilon \ ) \subset V. $$
>   Let 
>   $$ U \colon= (  a - \varepsilon/2, a + \varepsilon/2) \times (  b - \varepsilon/2, b + \varepsilon/2). $$ 
>   Then this $U$ is a basis set for the product space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and for any point $x \times y \in U$, we have 
>   $$ a - \varepsilon/2 < x < a+ \varepsilon/2  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  b - \varepsilon/2 < y < b + \varepsilon/2, $$
>   which together imply 
>   $$ a+b - \varepsilon < x+y < a+b + \varepsilon, $$
>   that is, 
>   $$f(x \times y) \in ( \ a+b - \varepsilon, \ a+b + \varepsilon \ ), $$ 
>   and hence $ f( x\times y) \in V$, which implies that $x \times y \in f^{-1}(V)$. So $U \subset f^{-1}(V)$.
>
> Thus for every point $a \times b \in f^{-1}(V)$ we can find a basis set $U$ for the product topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$ a \times b \in U \subset f^{-1} (V). $$
>   So $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in the product space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ whenever $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $f$ is continuous.

Is this proof correct?

Function $g$:

> Let $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. If $g^{-1}(V)$ is empty, then it is trivially open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. So let us assume that $g^{-1}(V)$ is non-empty. Let $a \times b \in g^{-1}(V)$. Then $a \times b \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $g(a \times b) = a-b \in V$. So there is a real number $\varepsilon > 0$ such that 
>   $$ ( \ a - b- \varepsilon, \ a - b + \varepsilon \ ) \subset V. $$
>   Let 
>   $$ U \colon= (  a - \varepsilon/2, a + \varepsilon/2) \times (  b - \varepsilon/2, b + \varepsilon/2). $$ 
>   Then this $U$ is a basis set for the product space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and for any point $x \times y \in U$, we have 
>   $$ a - \varepsilon/2 < x < a+ \varepsilon/2  \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  b - \varepsilon/2 < y < b + \varepsilon/2, $$
>   and so $$ -b - \varepsilon / 2 < -y < -b + \varepsilon / 2,$$
>   and therefore 
>   $$ a-b - \varepsilon < x- y < a- b + \varepsilon, $$
>   that is, 
>   $$g(x \times y) \in ( \ a - b - \varepsilon, \ a- b + \varepsilon \ ), $$ 
>   and hence $ g( x\times y) \in V$, which implies that $x \times y \in g^{-1}(V)$. So $U \subset g^{-1}(V)$.
>
> Thus for every point $a \times b \in g^{-1}(V)$ we can find a basis set $U$ for the product topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$ a \times b \in U \subset g^{-1} (V). $$
>   So $g^{-1}(V)$ is open in the product space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ whenever $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $g$ is continuous.

Am I right?

How to come up with a similar proof for each of the functions $h$ and $k$?

Comment: The general idea of these order based proofs can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/User:Dfeuer/Totally_Ordered_Group_with_Order_Topology_is_Topological_Group).

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct.  As for a proof for the function $h$, use the inequality
$$|xy-ab|\leq|x||y-b|+|b||x-a|$$
which is valid for all $a,b,x,y\in\mathbb R$.

For continuity of $k$, if you can prove that the map $l:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ given by $l(x)=x^{-1}$ is continuous, then $k(x,y)=h(x,l(y))$, so $k$ is continuous.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I would like to have a proof using the same approach as I've used for $f$ and $g$, independence of any metric argument.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud For $\mathbb{R}$ you now use the order and its properties heavily. But the metric topology is the same. You can choose one or the other, but you use specific properties in both cases.

Comment: For $g$, first show that $i(x) = -x$ is continuous (from it being order reversing if you're using the order representation, or being an isometry in the metric case), and note that $g(x,y) = f(x, i(y))$ as well.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud You can translate my hint into an order argument.  If $|x-a|<\varepsilon_1$ and $|y-b|<\varepsilon_2$, then $|x|<|a|+\varepsilon_1$, so $$|xy-ab|\leq(|a|+\varepsilon_1)\varepsilon_2+|b|\varepsilon_1$$ and thus $$-(|a|+\varepsilon_1)\varepsilon_2-|b|\varepsilon_1\leq xy-ab\leq(|a|+\varepsilon_1)\varepsilon_2+|b|\varepsilon_1.$$